# How to execute CROSS-ENV command vs code debugger?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, vscode-debugger

I am using npm start script like this

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=. nodemon index.js"
```

and now I want to debug app with nodemon and my launch.json file configuration is like this

```
    "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node-api-boilerplate/index.js",
            "restart": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
```

now I unable to understand that how to execute cross-env command.
Please help me.

error is something like this

```
Cannot find module 'src/container'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nodeProject\sailway education\node-api-boilerplate\index.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Comment: your launch.json will simply run runtimeExecutable+program: `nodemon ${workspaceFolder}/node-api-boilerplate/index.js`, so cross-env wont be even called in

Answer (score 1):

[Old question, but I've just encountered a similar case myself]

You can drop `cross-env`, and just use VS Code's `env` object. So your provided `launch.json` becomes:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "nodemon",
  "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node-api-boilerplate/index.js",
  "restart": true,
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "env": { "NODE_PATH": "." }
}
```